# problem with background image size

Tags: 12.04, resolution, desktop-background

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed and I just added a bunch of wallpapers. They look fine when opened using an image viewer, but when used as the actual desktop background they exceed the monitor size (i.e. parts of the image are cut off). I have an HP 15 with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and a 1366x768 screen with Intel HD 4000 graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Right Click` on the Desktop and select `Change Desktop Background`.

You can try the *`tile, zoom , center ,scale, fill, span`* options to fit the image according to your preference as shown.

[image]

Comment: thank you, how obvious it was, though i couldn't see it hh