# late 2019 18.04.3 LTS background images

Tags: desktop-background

I wanted to adjust the size of my desktop background image, but could not see any options in Settings -> background for doing so. I came here and found these two questions: [problem with background image size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551211/problem-with-background-image-size)  and  [How do I easily resize a wallpaper for my screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160248/how-do-i-easily-resize-a-wallpaper-for-my-screen). Both feature an image of Settings -> appearance with a number of options, and I have a vague memory that I had something like that once, but it is nowhere to be found now. These questions are 7 and 4 years old as of this writing. I did find something called 'Appearance' in the Ubuntu Store. Did this functionality get moved into that app?

I am no master of gimp, but I also tried using it to reduce the size of my image, and frankly, I can't even tell if Ubuntu accepted my 'set as background' command, because it still looks the same size. Are there any other options here?

Comment: Ok, yes, this is what I was looking for. I was able to follow the shell commands and I have also installed gnome-tweaks. All the reviews of gnome-tweaks are good, and they all say what I was thinking: Why isn't this the default?! Thank you.

Comment: Hi, lot of ppl think same as you.. gnome-tweaks should be included in the ISO.. may be GNOME devs will include in 2020?

Comment: We can only hope....

Comment: yes, recently I came to know that, there is a very well gnome-shell-extension called "dash to panel" lot of ppl were thinking lack of right and left placement of this app.. in Ubuntu 19.10 it is implemented.. similarly with lot of ppl requests.. they may add gnome-tweaks also.. https://askubuntu.com/a/1050683/739431